# error using soft delete onlyTrashed method with the query builder of Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, soft-delete

I would like to start using soft delete models with the query builder of Laravel

By the way, I created the column `deleted_at` and I implemented soft delete models in the model.

Request.php:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request as Req;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Request extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
}
```

RequestController function:

```
public function already_deleted_checker($id_req)
    {
        $request_customer_match_rip = DB::table('requests')->onlyTrashed()->select('id')->where('id', '=', $id_req)->get();

        $request_customer_match_rip_len = count($request_customer_match_rip);

        if ($request_customer_match_rip_len > 0) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

The function `already_deleted_checker` should check if the value in the deleted_at column is null or not... but unfortunately when I run the function I visualize the following error in the browser:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::onlyTrashed()
```

Can help?

Comment: Just a tip... avoid giving class names like: `Model, Request, Controller` because those already exist and sometimes it can bring only trouble!

Answer (score 2):

Why would you use DB instead of Eloquent Models ?

Simply :

```
 App\Request::onlyTrashed()->select('id')->where('id', '=', $id_req)->get();
```

DB facade doesn't know `onlyTrashed()` method.

Answer (score 1):

When using soft deletes, you should use the `Model` `QueryBuilder` instead of the generic one, actual in general you should 99% of the time use the `Model` `QueryBuilder`.

```
Request::onlyTrashed()->select('id')->where('id', $id_req)->get();
```

Comment: With your code it works however the value in the column "deleted_at" remains null when I delete a row... is it normal? I understood that the value should become the current timestamp.

Comment: you should also delete it as a model, Request::find($id)->delete();, looking at your initial code, i would assume you would use the DB::facade there too